# Another way of defining the Fréchet Derivative

Tags: calculus

Considering a mapping $f:U\mapsto V$, the vector function $f$ is said to be Fréchet differentiable at $\vec{x}_0$ if 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\|\vec{x}\|_U\to 0}\dfrac{\|f(\vec{x}+\vec{x}_0)-f(\vec{x}_0)-A\cdot\vec{x}\|_V}{\|\vec{x}\|_U}=0,
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a bounded linear operator. My question is: may I define the following way?
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\vec{x}\to \vec{0}}\dfrac{f(\vec{x}+\vec{x}_0)-f(\vec{x}_0)-A\cdot\vec{x}}{\|\vec{x}\|_U}=\vec{0}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Don't you define convergence in a normed space by norm?

Comment: I have seen both ways in literature but for me they don't mean the same thing. The first one is more common.